# Pure blue sky in Spring

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, earth-observation

I live in France.
Is it true that there are more occurrences of deep blue skies during spring. If yes why ?
Is it true also during autumn.
Thank you for answering

Comment: Welcome to Earth Science! What do you mean by 'deep blue skies'? This is a very subjective term.

Comment: Where in France do you live?  Do you mean clear skies in general?

Answer (score 0):

This is related to a similar question on April 29th in that the apparent colour of the sky is mainly caused by the absorption of different wavelengths of light by a wide range of atmospheric pollutants. I strongly suspect that if you compare the antecedent rainfall with the colour of the sky (in a given direction at a given time of day) you will find a marked correlation. The rain scrubs the atmosphere clean, so, facing away from the sun, you are likely to see a brighter blue after any period of significant rain.
So what is the typical amount of rain in spring, summer, autumn and winter, in your part of France?

Comment: I think this might be a comment rather than an answer to the specific question. If the question is not clear, let's ask for farther clarification.